# Script being used with Bginfo

Tags: vbscript

I use BGinfo to give me a bunch of different facts about my machine. One of the thing it does is run this external script which returns to a BGinfo Variable called `Public IP`:

```vb
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
o.open "GET", "http://ifconfig.me/ip", False
o.send
echo o.responseText
```

the problem is if for some reason the netcard has not got an proper connection or the website is not available the script errors with a diagbox which says

> Error evaluating scripted field 'Public IP' msxm13.dll line 4, position 0
>   the system cannot locate the resource specified

I was wondering how can I put an error trap in this VBScript that would catch the error and return for instance "no connection to the public IP"?

Answer (score 1):

```
On error resume next
<some code>
If err.number <> 0 then
    Msgbox err.number & " " & err.description
    err.clear
End If
```

Is the general form.